# linux + sysctl.conf configuration

Tags: linux, files, sysctl

Is it right to comment line with `#` in the file `sysctl.conf`?

I ask because I am not sure if the comment lines would be read or not.

```
more /etc/sysctl.conf

#net.core.rmem_default = 1048576
#net.core.rmem_max = 4194304
#net.core.wmem_default = 1048576
#net.core.wmem_max = 4194304


net.ipv4.tcp_timestamps=0
net.ipv4.tcp_sack=1
net.core.netdev_max_backlog=250000
net.core.rmem_max=4194304
net.core.wmem_max=4194304
net.core.rmem_default=4194304
net.core.wmem_default=4194304
net.core.optmem_max=4194304
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem=4096 87380 4194304
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem=4096 65536 4194304
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An excerpt from `man sysctl.conf`:

> Comments are denoted by a "#" at the beginning of a line.

Comment: I see that ";" is also kind of comment